# How to get first <p> from each of <description> in an XML file?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

I'm parsing a RSS feed to get the raw data and manipulate it.

On a WordPress RSS feed. I can find the *title*, *link*, *description* and publication of a the post by iterating over the `SimpleXMLElement`. The nodes are located in:

```
$title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
$link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
$description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
$pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
```

respectively.

The problem is `$description` had 2 `<p>`s inside. One one which is useless for me; the second one.

So how do I assign `$description` to only the first `<p>` of description?

Getting simply `$xml->channel->item[$i]->description->p[0]` won't work. It results in an internal server error.

My whole code looks like this:

```
<?php 
$html = "";
$url = "http://sntsh.com/posts/feed/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
    $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
    $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description->children();
    $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;

    $html .= "<a href='$link'><h3>$title</h3></a>";
    $html .= "$description";
    $html .= "<br />$pubDate";
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `description->children()` to get the children as an array? http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

Comment: Am I reading correctly, you have the description from the RSS feed set to a variable (e.g. `$desc = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description`). Now, you need to get a substring of that description? (specifically the content of the second set of `<p>` tags)

Comment: Yes! I will replace description with that modified substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the children of an element using the `children()` method. If you can guarantee that the first child will always be the element that you need, you can use it this way:

```
$title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
$link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
$description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description->children();
$pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
```

The `children()` function is meant to be used in an iterative manner, where every time you call it it returns the next child as a `SimpleXMLElement`. http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

**Edit**
It seems that the cause of the issue are the `<![CDATA[` `]]>` tags. They cause the SimpleXMLElement to be empty. Stripping them fixes it:

```
$html = '';
$src = file_get_contents('http://sntsh.com/posts/feed/');
$search = ["<![CDATA[","]]>"];
$replace = array('','');
$data = str_replace($search,$replace,$src);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

for($i = 0; $i < count($xml->channel->item); $i++)
{
    $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
    $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
    $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description->children();
    // Or
    // $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description->p[0];
    $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;

    $html .= "<a href='$link'><h3>$title</h3></a>";
    $html .= trim($description).'...';
    $html .= "<br />$pubDate";
}
echo $html;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Results in internal server error `500`.

Comment: You should check your server log then. It's not a PHP issue.

Comment: I just noticed that your description is wrapped in a `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` which causes the description SimpleXML object to be empty. Do you have any control over that?

Comment: I think no! Internally managed by WordPress. Even if there is, I don't want to change default settings. There must be some way to overcome.

Comment: Getting empty page. :(

Comment: @SantoshKumar Sorry, one of the variables was named wrong. It's working now, I've tested it.